# How to call different function on selecting different option from drop down in angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript1.7

Many number of drop downs are to be used. Requirement is when a option from drop down is selected corresponding custom function is need to be called, as in below what should be in place of opt.mtd as its not working

html

```
<li class ="dropdown"> 
<div id="name">Activities</div>
<li *ngFor="let opt of activityList">
<a (click)=opt.mtd>{{opt.name}}</a>
</li>
</li>
```

Component

```
export class..{

activityList=[{mtd:"getActivity1()", name:"cycling"},
{Mtd:"getActivity2()", name:"swimming"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the value of `mtd` is just a string. You need to pass the actual function.

```
function getActivity1() {...};
function getActivity2() {...};

activityList=[
    {mtd: getActivity1, name:"cycling"},
    {mtd: getActivity2, name:"swimming"}
]
```

Also, remove the `()` after the assignment, you don't want to execute the functions here, you just want to assign them to use them later in `(click)`.

Comment: Thanks  lukas, I'll try n will let u know the result.

Comment: Also in template it should be (click)=opt.mtd()